# Where in the TaNa"kh is there a discussion about how to slaughter an animal?

Tags: sources-mekorot, tanach, slaughter-shochet-shecht

Where in the TaNa"kh is there a discussion about how to slaughter an animal?

When reading various parashot, one sometimes come across about the topic of slaughtering animals, but (the ones I have read, offer) no description about how to do it.

Comment: [Ezra 1:9](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt35a01.htm#9) lists 29 knives among the treasures brought back to the Temple. This is consistent with the knives being a) necessary for proper Temple function, b) expertly made of precious  material ([meteoric iron?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meteoric_iron)) so they could maintain a hyper-clean edge during repeated use.

Answer (score 19):

There is no description in the Torah (and to the best of my knowledge in the rest of TaNa"KH) as to how to correctly slaughter an animal.

In fact, R. Yehuda HaLevi ([Kuzari, 3:35](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_Kuzari.3.35?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) brings this as a proof to the truth of the Oral Law. How can the written Torah demands slaughter without giving any details? It must be that there exists a parallel, oral tradition which explains how to slaughter correctly.

The written Torah itself seems to hint at this well. [Devarim 12:21](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.12.21?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) reads:

> וְזָבַחְתָּ מִבְּקָרְךָ וּמִצֹּאנְךָ אֲשֶׁר נָתַן ה' לְךָ כַּאֲשֶׁר צִוִּיתִךָ וְאָכַלְתָּ
>
> you shall slaughter from your cattle and your flocks, which Hashem has given you, as I have commanded you and eat.

As Rashi there comments (*s.v.* "[וזבחת … כאשר צויתך](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.12.21?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Deuteronomy.12.21.2&lang2=bi)"):

> למדנו שיש צווי בזביחה היאך ישחוט והן הלכות שחיטה שנאמרו למשה מסיני
>
> We have thus learned that there is a commandment as to how to slaughter, and these are the laws of slaughter which were said to Moshe [orally] at Sinai.

Comment: The key phrase is Moshe telling the people -- "do it *as I commanded you*", yet there are no other written details. (Then again, it's the kind of thing that you would actually learn best by watching someone do, not by reading a text.) It's in the Oral Law; the Mishna in Chulin goes the basic precepts.

Comment: @Shalom put a link here on "the Mishna in Chulin".

Comment: @ninamag Mishna https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Chullin.1?lang=bi ; Rambam's Mishna Torah (very clearly organized): https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Ritual_Slaughter.1?lang=bi

Comment: @Shalom So the command how to slaughter came from Moshe, but he did not explicitly write it down.

Comment: @ninamag in the Written Tanach, Moshe (speaking for God) says "do it like I told you." Our oral tradition then tells us what those details were.

Comment: @ninamag yes thatst he whole point, look at the begiinning of Rambam (the cycle just started), the whole point is that the entire oral law / details werent written down (except in individual notes), it was passed down only orally, thats why its the oral torah

Comment: That's a sure proof that Avraham wore a Shtreiml - how could he go outside without one. Pretty lame, sorry. The Sages phrased it simply - "לא בשמים היא" - if G-d doesn't care - we will - we will propagate any laws we want. But I retracted my downvote as you clearly preserve the tradition.

Comment: @AlBerko How do you understand the verse saying כאשר צויתיך regarding *shechitah*?

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the above answer, there is a part of the after-slaughtering process mentioned directly in the Torah in [Vayikra 17:13](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9754&st=&pgnum=228&hilite=) that states that after slaughtering a wild animal or bird, one should spill the blood onto the ground and cover it with dirt.

Comment: So wouldn't this technically disqualify the above answer, since @JoelK said that there is no reference in the Tanach on how to slaughter an animal? Additionally, this would also clash with R' Yehudah HaLevi and Rashi about how the laws of slaughter are something solely of Oral Law (and additionally provide proof for its existence). Interesting. +1

Comment: @DanF +1 for a very appropriate answer, which indeed appears to disqualify the previous answer.

Comment: @ezra "So wouldn't this technically disqualify the above answer" - Debatable. Covering the animals blood is after the actual slaughtering, itself. OP asks "how to slaughter". AFAIK, there is nothing in the Torah that specifies that it must be done with a special knife, where the cut should be, etc.

Comment: @DanF I agree that this passage sounds like "after the actual slaughtering", but is it possible that the Torah suggests that "a special knife" is not always the preferred method, as in שָׂא-נָא כֵלֶיךָ, תֶּלְיְךָ וְקַשְׁתֶּךָ, "take, I pray thee, thy weapons, thy quiver and thy bow" (Bereishith 27:3), which is what Isaac said to his son, in order to slaughter an animal for him.

Comment: @ninamag You cited an interesting verse. However I don't think this is a good example of deducing kosher slaughtering laws. First of all, Isaac lived long before the Torah was given (Yes, I know the well-known Midrash says that the forefathers performed all the Torah mitzvoth. It's a Midrash, and not every aspect of that can be literal.) Second, Esav was a hunter and these were the tools that he used to hunt. So, Isaac was referring to common terminology. It's certainly possible that at that time, animals did not need to be slaughtered as they are now. You may want to pose this as a new Q.

Comment: @DanF My question that I posted asked about "how to slaughter an animal"  without attaching to it a reason, such as for eating purposes. Having said that, David HaMelekh slaughtered animals by clubbing it to death, or perhaps by using the same weapon(s) as he did to kill Goliath, because David described how he would slaughter Goliath, in the same way as David slaughtered bears and lions:  וְיָצָאתִי אַחֲרָיו וְהִכִּתִיו, וְהִצַּלְתִּי מִפִּיו; וַיָּקָם עָלַי--וְהֶחֱזַקְתִּי בִּזְקָנוֹ, וְהִכִּתִיו וַהֲמִיתִּיו. (Samuel 1, Chapter 17, verse 34-36)

Comment: @ninamag The reference to slaughtering animals on that requires details is for food (*shechitah*) the statements about other kinds like King David is killing for non-food like self defense. The reference to covering the blood is after having slaughtered as in the oral law.

Comment: @sabbahillel i agree. i brought up a possible way to (mis)read my own posted question, but yes, my posted question was referring to food purposes.

Comment: Part of the process is described in connection with the Akeidah including the special knife. Similarly, the requirement for a perfectly sharp knife (at that time made from knapped flint) is mentioned in connection with Tzipporah's circumcision of her son on the way to Egypt.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Do you have TaNa"Kh sources about the connection of the "sharp knife" to slaughtering animals? The one that you mentioned associates a "sharp knife" with "circumcision".

Comment: @YaacovDeane that is a very good point about the connection of the special knife with the Akeidah-Sh'chet,  וַיִּשְׁלַח אַבְרָהָם אֶת-יָדוֹ, וַיִּקַּח אֶת-הַמַּאֲכֶלֶת, לִשְׁחֹט, אֶת-בְּנוֹ (Bereishith 22:10); the next point to prove now is, where does it teach where the knife is to be applied (yes, we now know at the neck area), but where in the TaNa"KH does it say that?

Comment: In fact, it does not have to be with a knife (helpful to those searching the TaNa"Kh), because הַשּׁוֹחֵט בְּמַגַּל יָד, בְּצוֹר, וּבְקָנֶה, שְׁחִיטָתוֹ כְשֵׁרָה. https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Chullin.1.2?lang=bi

Comment: @ninamag These things you are bringing from Chullin are all different types of blades.

Comment: @YaacovDeane The particular sentence I quoted, which I had read in English, reads, "If one slaughters with a hand sickle, a flint stone, or with a reed, his slaughter is valid." If "a hand sickle, a flint stone, or with a reed" ... "are all different types of blades", then fair enough. I just did not immediately associate the English words "stone" or "reed" as a cutting "blade", but yes, of course, they can be.

Comment: @ninamag A hand sickle has several understandings of what it is. Most views are that is has a curve, is made of metal and the blade (cutting edge) is on a particular side of the curve. A flint is a knapped stone. It is incredibly sharp but over the length required has a series of arcs. Flint knives are the oldest. Reeds are a straight edge, but are not as sharp as a flint and generally don't last as long. If you are interested in this subject, you can search You Tube for 'primitive survival tools'. It helps in understanding what the Torah is actually discussing.

Comment: Flint knife photo: https://www.couteaux-berthier.com/boutique_us/images_produits/pmGinelli10.jpg

Comment: Example of a reed knife made from bamboo: http://japantool-iida.com/knife/images/bamboo2.jpg.jpg

Comment: Example of a hand sickle: https://www.amazon.com/Various-Japanese-Sickle-JAPANESE-SICKLE/dp/B000AYIYAE

Comment: "וְזָבַחְתָּ מִבְּקָרְךָ וּמִצֹּאנְךָ" so can't be...

Answer (score 3):

The Rambam in [Hilchos Shechita 1: 4](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/971827/jewish/Shechitah-Chapter-1.htm) explicitly states that all the details of kosher slaughter are given as *halacha LeMoshe miSinai* through the oral law only.

> The slaughter which the Torah mentions without elaboration must be
>   explained so that we know: a) which place in the animal is
>   [appropriate] for ritual slaughter?, b) what is the measure of the
>   slaughtering process?, c) with what do we slaughter?, d) when do we
>   slaughter?, e) in which place [on the animal's neck] do we slaughter?
>   f) how do we slaughter, g) what factors disqualify the slaughter? h)
>   who can slaughter?<sup>14</sup>
>
> We were commanded concerning all of these factors in the Torah with
>   the verse [Deuteronomy
>   12:21](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9976#showrashi=true&v=21): "And
>   you shall slaughter from your cattle... as I commanded you." All of
>   these factors were commanded to us orally as is true with regard to
>   the remainder of the Oral Law which is called "the mitzvah," as we
>   explained in the beginning of this text.<sup>15</sup>
>
> <sup>14.</sup> In the following chapters, the Rambam proceeds to
>   answer all of these questions.
>
> <sup>15.</sup> I.e., in the Introduction that precedes Hilchot Yesodei
>   HaTorah. There the Rambam explains that the Oral Law is called "the
>   mitzvah," because it gives us instruction concerning the observance of
>   the mitzvot. Without it, we would not know how to fulfill them.

Note as Rashi there [writes](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.12.21?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Deuteronomy.12.21.2&lang2=bi):

> **וזבחת וגו' כאשר צויתך**: למדנו שיש צווי בזביחה היאך ישחוט, והן הלכות
>   שחיטה שנאמרו למשה בסיני:
>
> **you may slaughter… as I have commanded you:** We learn [from here] that there is a commandment regarding slaughtering, how one must
>   slaughter. [Since this commandment is not written in the Torah we
>   deduce that] these are the laws of ritual slaughtering given orally to
>   Moses on [Mount] Sinai. — [Sifrei ; Chul. 28a]

Comment: That translation, "as is true with regard to", is not an accurate translation of the wording used by Rambam. Rambam is only explaining how he clarifies the meaning of the word 'mitzvah' and it's usage to mean that it is an indication of the Oral Torah. That is one understanding and tradition. Not necessarily the only one.

Answer (score 1):

[Deuteronomy 12:16](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.12.16?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) states:

> :רַ֥ק הַדָּ֖ם לֹ֣א תֹאכֵ֑לוּ עַל־הָאָ֥רֶץ תִּשְׁפְּכֶ֖נּוּ כַּמָּֽיִם
>
> However, you shall not eat the blood; you shall spill it on the ground like water.

[Deuteronomy 12](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.12.1-31?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) is the chapter in the Torah that commands us how to slaughter an animal.

We are taught to do it in such a manner that we are NOT to "eat the blood" but to "spill [the blood] on the ground like water", as opposed to other unkosher ways of slaughter, which does not include a proper drainage of blood.

This is the simplest (pshat) biblical requirement of slaughter. The rest, as found in the Talmud, Oral Law, etc., is expanded commentary.